# Disable Access if Logged in

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security. I need to block the access to Login page if user is authenticated. The following line is giving error.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="!IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
```

Error is unsupported configuration.

Comment: What about using <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()"></sec:authorize> taglib in your login page?

Answer (score 0):

either you can use IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY (to allow access only if user is authenticated anonymously), or enable expressions and use IsAuthenticated() like given below

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**"
        access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    ...
  </http>
```